# Como criar rotas para usuários autenticados com React JS e Firebase

Tags: react, firebase, react-router

estou criando uma aplicação onde criei um sistema de login com firebase. E eu consigo o retorno de uma variavel com os dados do usuário logado. Mas estou com dificuldade para direcionar as rotas. Minha dúvida é essa:

Como eu crio rotas privadas para o react js com firebase?

Segue meu codigo:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import {onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import {auth} from '../../firebase-config'
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Cadastro from '../Cadastro/Cadastro';
import Preferences from '../Preferences/Preferences';
import Login from '../Login/Login';

export default function Rotas (){
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
                    <Route path="/cadastro" element={<Cadastro/>}/>
                    <Route path="/preferences" element={<Preferences/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )} else {
            return(
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            )
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Consegui resolver pessoal! Basta usar a funcão Render() ao invés de Return().